# How can a recipe get a full list of the server tags?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, rightscale

How can a recipe get a full list of the server tags?

or

How can a recipe check if a certain tag is set/present?

BTW: tagged? didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

You can get all the tags of a node in recipe by `node.tags` or `node[:tags]`. So to check, if the certain tag is present, you need to:

```
node[:tags].include? 'mytag'
```

To get the full list of all the tags on all nodes you have to use search.

```
search( :node, '*:*' ).collect(:tags).flatten.uniq
```

But `tagged? 'mytag'` should work actually. Show your code.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @IgorM. my code is `if tagged?("au")` and I get an error: `TemplateError (undefined method `tagged?' for...`

Comment: I came across method called tagged? in Chef::Recipe .I want to check for some tag say 'active'. How do I get? http://www.rubydoc.info/github/opscode/chef/master/Chef/Recipe

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things to keep in mind with Chef tags:

1. **You cannot use them in attribute files**. It would be awesome if you could, but it just doesn't work. This is what you will see if you try: ERROR: Undefined node attribute or method 'tagged?' on node'.
2. This may be fixed in later versions of Chef, but there was a time when you would get errors when checking for tags if the node was not tagged at all.

Those two things aside, I use them a lot in recipes and they work very well.

```
if tagged?('legacy')
  do legacy things
end
```

or

```
return if tagged?('ignore')
```

Those types of uses should work, no problem, from your recipes.

Comment: You can still access them you just don't get the tagged? method which is a member of the Recipe class. you have to access them like a normal attribute IE `node['tags'].include?()`